# How to improve the resulted bar plot for data.frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two data.frame that needed to produce bar plot in single grid. I obtained these data.frame as result of benchmark the algorithm in R. To do that, getting plot data where two data.frame must be merged to one. I've learned earlier post of this sort of question in `SO`, and get own idea how to get the bar plot. However, my resulted plot is not well readable, I think something needs to be done on my code. Can any one point me how to improve the resulted plot in better way ?

reproducible data :

using two `cvs` file to benchmark algorithm:

```
bnch_2 <- data.frame(
    test=c("s3","s7","s4" ,"s1" ,"s2" ,"s5" ,"s6" ,"s9","s8"),
    replications=c(10,10, 10, 10 ,10 ,10 ,10 ,10 ,10),
    elapsed=c(0.23,  0.28,  0.53 , 0.80 , 4.12 , 8.57 , 8.81 ,20.16 ,24.53),
    relative=c( 1.000 ,  1.217 ,  2.304 ,  3.478 , 17.913 , 37.261 , 38.304 , 87.652 ,106.652),
    user.self=c(0.23, 0.28 , 0.53 , 0.61 , 4.13 , 8.55 , 8.80 ,18.06 ,19.08),
    sys.self=c(0.00, 0.00 ,0.00, 0.00 ,0.00, 0.00 ,0.00 ,0.13, 0.51)
)
```

using three `csv` file to benchmark same algorithm :

```
bnch_3 <- data.frame(
    test=c("s3", "s7" ,"s4", "s1", "s5", "s6","s2", "s9","s8"),
    replications=c(10,10, 10, 10 ,10 ,10 ,10 ,10 ,10),
    elapsed=c( 0.34 , 0.47 , 0.70 , 2.41  ,8.26 , 8.75 , 9.03, 28.78 ,36.56),
    relative=c( 1.000 ,  1.382 ,  2.059  , 7.088 , 24.294 , 25.735 , 26.559  ,84.647 ,107.529),
    user.self=c(0.34 , 0.46  ,0.70 , 1.72 , 8.26 , 8.74  ,9.01, 26.24 ,30.95),
    sys.self=c(0.00 ,0.00 ,0.00, 0.12, 0.00 ,0.00 ,0.00, 0.12 ,0.77)
)
```

I used `bind_rows` to get single data.frame and possibly get bar plot in this way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

DF <- bind_rows(bnch_2, bnch_3)
ggplot(DF$elapsed, aes(factor(test))) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

but my code has some problem and couldn't produce my desired plot. In order to produce more readable bar plot, perhaps I increase the scale of my input data to make plot well distinguishable. How can I make this happen ?

This is desired plot I want to achieve :

[image]

How can I improve the code for getting bar plot ? How can I achieve my desired bar plot ? Any idea please ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Said ggplot2 code doesn't generate _anything_ (it errors out). It'd prbly be worth the time to go through a few tutorials on ggplot2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an additional column containing the `type` , e.g.

```
DF = bind_rows(bnch_2, bnch_3, .id = "type")
# or add in the column
#DF$type = rep(c("A", "B"), each=9)
```

Then plot using `fill`

```
g = ggplot(DF, aes(factor(test), elapsed)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = type), position = "dodge")
```

To match the `theme` of your example plot, `theme_tufte` looks a good match

```
library(ggthemes)
g +   theme_tufte()
```

To give you

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. How can I possibly rename the `xlab`, `ylab` by custom ?

Comment: `+xlab("XXX") + ylab("YYY")`

Comment: @Dan, You could find that with a 10 second search.